# What should you do to gracefully release all the resources when restart a flink job/job is doing a failover?

Tags: tcp, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have a flink job that holds some IO resources like tcp connections, etc. We always surround our connection function with a finally block to close the connection and release the connection in the close() method in all the operators. But we found that the connection are not released when the failover happened from time to time since we found a lot of CLOSE_WAIT state in our server side. We guess that flink may use some interruption method to restart the job so that the code doesn't go to the finally block. What would be a proper way to release the resource when flink is doing a failover?

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to access the flink life cycle of the function, you should implement your logic within the user-defined function, implementing the `RichFunction` interface. This class defines methods for the life cycle of the functions, as well as methods to access the context in which the functions are executed.

Among the others, this interface exposes the `close()` method which is supposed to be used for clean up work:

```java
    /**
     * Tear-down method for the user code. It is called after the last call to the main working methods
     * (e.g. <i>map</i> or <i>join</i>). For functions that  are part of an iteration, this method will
     * be invoked after each iteration superstep.
     *
     * <p>This method can be used for clean up work.
     *
     * @throws Exception Implementations may forward exceptions, which are caught by the runtime. When the
     *                   runtime catches an exception, it aborts the task and lets the fail-over logic
     *                   decide whether to retry the task execution.
     */
    void close() throws Exception;
```

So, I believe the `close()` function is the proper place to gracefully release your resources.

Comment: We actually implemented those releasing logic in all the close() methods. But actually when for whatever reason the connections are not closed when the job restart happened. As I mentioned above, we guess flink may use some interruption method to restart the job so that the code doesn't go to the finally block or close() method